# How to repeat the Insert command in C# to SQL Server database 3 times consecutively

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm new here and im really having trouble with this part of the code. I need to repeat the Insert multiple times consecutively based on the given quantity.

```
int ctr = int.Parse(txtquantity3.ToString());
int x=0;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_books (Book_num,Call_Num, Book_Title, Book_Author, Book_Publisher, Book_Quantity, Book_Pages, genre , Book_available,book_status) VALUES (@Bn, @Cn, @Title, @Author, @Publisher, @Quantity, @Pages, @Genre, @Available, @Status)");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = con;

MessageBox.Show("Save successful!");

while (x <= ctr)
{
    x += 1;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bn", txtbooknum3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cn", txtcallnum3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txttitle3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", txtauthor3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Publisher", txtpublisher3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtquantity3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pages", txtpages3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", txtgenre3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Available", txtquantity3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Available");

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: And what is going wrong?

Comment: everytime i try inserting a new value, it will only insert once in my database even if i set the quantity to 3

Comment: Is there a reason you want to add 3 rows with the same information to your table? I see nothing here that is driving different data with each loop so even if you get this figured out you have 3 duplicate rows in your database with the only difference being an autogenerated primary key (if used). Now it looks like you are already placeing txtquantity3.text in your Available field so if you're doing this because you have 3 books, then you should only need to insert the single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use AddWithValue in that way. The SqlCommand instance is always the same so calling AddWithValue a second time with the same parameter name produces an exception. You need to add, at every loop a call to

```
 while (x <= ctr)
 {
     x+=1;
     cmd.Parameters.Clear();
     ....

 }
```

However your code could be changed to create the parameter collection before entering the loop and inside the loop changing only the parameter value.
A full example on how to rewrite your code introducing a better Handling of the connection is the following....

```
// Using statement to close and dispose on exit
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO tbl_books 
            (Book_num,Call_Num, Book_Title, Book_Author, 
            Book_Publisher, Book_Quantity, Book_Pages, genre , 
            Book_available,book_status) 
            VALUES (@Bn, @Cn, @Title, @Author, @Publisher, @Quantity, 
            @Pages, @Genre, @Available, @Status)", con))
{
    // Open the connection just one time here
    con.Open();

    // Create all the parameters required SPECIFYING the correct datatype
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bn", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    ...... declare other parameters....

    // Start your loop  
    while (x <= ctr)
    {
        x+=1;

        cmd.Parameters["@bn"].Value = txtbooknum3.Text;
        .... set the value for other parameters at each loop ....
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Finally, if all you need is to insert a specific number of record all with the same values then just call the Adds setting the values before entering the loop and execute the ExecuteNonQuery the required number of times without changing anything in the parameter collection

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO tbl_books 
            (Book_num,Call_Num, Book_Title, Book_Author, 
            Book_Publisher, Book_Quantity, Book_Pages, genre , 
            Book_available,book_status) 
            VALUES (@Bn, @Cn, @Title, @Author, @Publisher, @Quantity, 
            @Pages, @Genre, @Available, @Status)", con))
{
    con.Open();
    // Create all the parameters required SPECIFYING the correct datatype
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtbooknum3.Text;
    ...... declare other parameters and set the value before the loop....

    // Start your loop  
    while (x <= ctr)
    {
        x+=1;
        // Just execute the query three times
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: and he can open connection once.

Comment: i did like what u said. but it is still inserting into the database once. do you think maybe it has something to do with my Primary key being set to auto increment

Comment: that should be `cnn.Open();` But I'm sure you fixed that in your implementation.

Comment: @Mat do you have any try/catch around this code? If yes, remove it and let the exception to be seen. And how do you know the fact that the insert is executed just one time?

Comment: @Steve Thank you. it already worked. apparently there was something wrong with my C#. i try rebooting and then it suddenly started working. Again thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to open a connection each time you want to execute a command. Open it before your while loop, and close it after.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all of the other suggestions about proper user of ADO.

That said, what is `txtquantity3`?  From the way you use it it looks like a TextBox control.  If so, then your first line should be

`int ctr = int.Parse(txtquantity3.text);`